# Pass Data from selected value from Vue.JS drop-down to a C# MVC POST controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vue.js, model-view-controller

I have a Form that is mostly built in ASP.NET MVC. I have been asked to add a new field and other functionality to the form. I gave up on the ideas of using the ASP.NET razor syntax to add those features after struggling with it for sometime, I decided to go with using Vue.JS to build those functionalities.

The problem now is that although, I have built the necessary feature on the front-end, I have been struggling to find a way to pass the selected item of a drop down to the MVC controller being used, note the controller already exist as follows.

```
 [Route("request-withdrawal"), HttpGet]
        public ActionResult RequestWithdrawal(string customerId = null, string coreSystem = null, string portfolioCode = null)
        {
            var currentUser = GetCurrentUser();
            var accounts = _accountService.GetAllByUser(currentUser.Id);
            ViewBag.DropdownList = WithdrawalRequest.GetWithdrawalList();
            var request = new WithdrawalRequest();
            return View(request);
        }
```

I do not need to make any modifications the code above. It is when the user wants to submit the form that I need to pass the value selected in the Vue.JS powered drop down list and send to the MVC POST controller for processing. That method looks like this.

```
 [Route("request-withdrawal"), HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RequestWithdrawal(WithdrawalRequest request)
        {
            bool isError = !ModelState.IsValid;

            if (!isError)
            {
                try
                {
                    var resp = fluentApiClient.NewPostRequest("investnow", "save-withdrawal-request")
                        .AddBody(request.GetPayload()).GetResponse();

                    if (resp.Success)
                    {
                        ViewBag.Message = resp.Message;
                        isError = false;
                        return RedirectToAction(nameof(SuccessWithdrawal), new { resp.Message });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", resp.Message);
                        isError = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (ApiException e)
                {
                    isError = true;
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", e);
                }
            }

            var currentUser = GetCurrentUser();
            ViewBag.DropdownList = WithdrawalRequest.GetWithdrawalList();
            return View(request);
        }
```

My thoughts are 
 1. I'm not sure I can use a URL query param since I'm not calling the POST method with Vue.
 2. I'm thinking perhaps a hidden field will work somehow but I'm not sure how exactly.

Also note that the Vue.JS powered drop down list get its data from an API endpoint.

Please help. Kindly advice how I should do this.

Thanks

What I want to do is pass the selected value from the Vue.JS powered drop down list to that controller action above.

Comment: For your thought number one: Are you using URL query params when calling your GET method? That would be fine. What troubles you there?
And regarding your second thought: Why using a hidden field? Give your vue select element a v-model and use the value from the selected option when calling your C# Controller method:

`<select v-model="selected">
  <option value="abc">ABC</option>
</select>`